# Google app script time trigger not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have this code:

```
const triggerFunctionName = "getScoreEntries";

function onOpen(){
  const submenu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Automatic " + entityBeingToggled).addItem("Turn On", "enableUpdates").addSeparator().addItem("Turn Off", "disableUpdates");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Score Tools").addSubMenu(submenu).addSeparator().addItem("Update Now", triggerFunctionName).addToUi();
}

function enableUpdates(){
  if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("triggerExists")){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(entityBeingToggled + " already turned on, by the user: " + PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("triggerOwner"), "Error");
    return;
  }
  ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers().forEach(trigger => ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger));
  // ScriptApp.newTrigger(triggerFunctionName).timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(8).create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(triggerFunctionName).timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(10).nearMinute(14).create();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(entityBeingToggled + " enabled successfully.", "Turned On");
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("triggerOwner", Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()); 
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("triggerExists", true); 
}
```

edit:

```
 const getScoreEntries = () => {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Processing Report...", "Please wait...", 10);
  const [entryHeaders, ...entryData] = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(DATA_ENTRY_SHEETNAME).getDataRange().getValues();
  const auditIdHeaderIndex = entryHeaders.indexOf(AUDIT_ID_HEADERNAME);
  const headerIndicesToKeep = [auditIdHeaderIndex ,...entryHeaders.map((h, i) => validScoreHeader(h)?i:"no").filter(i => i !== "no")];
  const relevantHeaders = entryHeaders.filter((h,i) => headerIndicesToKeep.includes(i)).map(h => h.toString());
  const relevantData = entryData.map(row => row.filter((v, i) => headerIndicesToKeep.includes(i))).filter(row => row[relevantHeaders.indexOf(AUDIT_ID_HEADERNAME)].toString().trim());
  const normalizedData = relevantData.map(row => row.map((c, i) => {
    if(i == auditIdHeaderIndex) return c.toString();
    c = c.toString().trim();
    if(c === "") return "";
    let n = Number(c);
    return isNaN(n)?"":n;
  }));
  const outputData = aggregateAllRows(entryHeaders, entryData);
  if(!outputData.length){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("No data to process...", "Empty", 10);
    return
  }
  let currentReportSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(RESULT_SSID).getSheetByName(RESULT_SHEET_NAME);
  let nRowsToClear = currentReportSheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  if(nRowsToClear > 0) currentReportSheet.getRange(2,1,nRowsToClear, currentReportSheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  currentReportSheet.getRange(2,1,outputData.length, outputData[0].length).setValues(outputData);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Report Generated Successfully, please see the report sheet for results...", "Success...", 10);
}
```

so what happens here is that I am trying to trigger the event to run at 10:14am every day. However, it doesn't actually run, ever. The only time it runs is when I hit 'update now' and it'll manually run, but the time based trigger doesn't work. In the 'triggers' section of app scripts, it shows the trigger, but shows it's never being executed.

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas on what the problem may be, and if you need anymore info to debug. thank you in advance

Comment: Please include `triggerFunctionName`.  And did you check the exection log to see if `triggerFunctionName` is triggering or error out?

Comment: the only time it executes is when I manually push the button, not when I run it automatically. I've updated the question to include triggerFunctionName

Comment: @TheWizEd what I meant in the previous comment is that when It runs automatically, the execution logs don't show anything, whereas when I manually push the button, it shows the execution.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with installable triggers except through the script editor trigger dialog.  But should you be associating the trigger with the spreadsheet see [ScriptApp.newTrigger()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String))?

Comment: @TheWizEd yeah I actually originally had that but it didn't work so took it out. same problem. thanks for your input tho mate :)

Comment: I would start with a simplier function for `enableUpdates` and `getScoreEntries` and build it up until it breaks.  I would also remove all the `toast` because it can not run in a timed trigger.

Comment: try re-ordering your time-based trigger definition with the everyDays(1) last: .timeBased().atHour(10).nearMinute(14).everyDays(1).create()

Answer (score 0):

I believe your trigger definition needs to be ordered with the everydays() behind the atHour() and nearMinute() like this:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger(triggerFunctionName).timeBased().atHour(10).nearMinute(14).everyDays(1).create();
```